# Why is my UIToolbar appearing in an odd position?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitoolbar, uikeyboard

I want add a `UIToolbar` to the keyboard for my `UITextField`. Here is the code I'm using:

```
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                                  target:self 
                                                                  action:@selector(someFunction)];
    doneButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UISegmentedControl *directionControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Back", @"Next", nil]];
    directionControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    directionControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    [directionControl addTarget:self action:@selector(directionControlPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    UIBarButtonItem *segItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:directionControl];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:segItem, flexibleSpace, doneButton, nil]];

    // Assign the toolbar to the text fields
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
```

However, here is what it looks like when I run the code:

[image]

The `toolbar` doesn't seem to be high enough; also I notice that the tint colour of the toolbar hasn't been acknowledged.

Please can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you need to set the toolbar's frame, at least its size. As I recall, I used `[toolbar sizeToFit]` to get the height and had to use the window width to get the width.

Comment: This worked perfectly! It resolved the height, width and also fixed the tint colour. Thank you very much!

Comment: The tint wasn't showing because the toolbar's size was `CGSizeZero`.